# Função com insert de acordo com um select que retorna uma lista de ID's - Postgresql

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, trigger

Preciso fazer uma trigger `after insert` que chama uma função que pegue o último registro inserido em certa tabela e insira o ID desse último registro em outra tabela de acordo com um `select` que retorna vários ID's. EX:

```
tb_1  
.-------------.
|  ID  | NOME |  
.-------------.    
|   1  |   A  | 
|   2  |   B  | 
|   3  |   C  | <- Último ID inserido  
'------'------' 

tb_2  
.-------------.
|  ID  | NOME |  
|------|------| 
|  41  |  AAA |  
|  42  |  BBB | 
|  43  |  CCC |  
|  44  |  AAA |  
|  45  |  AAA |  
'------'------'   

INSERT INTO tb_3 (tb_1_id,tb_2_id)  
VALUES (
        (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tb_1), 
        (SELECT ID FROM tb_2 WHERE NOME = 'AAA')
       )  


tb_3  
.----------.----------.  
|  tb_1_id |  tb_2_id | 
|----------|----------| 
|     3    |    41    |
|     3    |    44    |
|     3    |    45    |
'----------'----------'
```

Como fazer um `insert` que faz essa lógica que mostrei? É possível?
As estruturas da `trigger` e `function` eu faço depois.

Comment: Não me parece ser possível por trigger pois são duas tabelas

Comment: Você basicamente explicou o comportamento, faz sentido sua lógica pra mim. Tenta fazer, caso tiver algum problema faça uma pergunta do respectivo problema.

Comment: Eu quero saber se é possível fazer um insert nesse tipo, pois o exemplo que mostrei da errado, mas a lógica é essa.

Comment: **Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre! Vote consciente!** O seu voto é muito importante para nossa comunidade, contribua conosco e ajude a tornar a Stack Overflow em Português (SOpt) cada vez maior. Você pode saber mais em: [**Vote cedo, vote frequentemente**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente)

Comment: Você já avaliou o uso da cláusula RETURNING do comando INSERT? Creio que ela possa facilitar seu procedimento.

Answer (score 1):

O que você quer fazer é inserir esses ids em uma tabela de ligação, mas pelo que entendi essa `tab_2` retorna vários ids, então no final das contas o `insert` fica assim:

```
INSERT INTO tb_3 (tb_1_id,1) 
INSERT INTO tb_3 (tb_1_id,2)
INSERT INTO tb_3 (tb_1_id,3)
```

Três ids da `tb_2` para o mesmo `id` da `db_1`.

O que você pode fazer é um `FOR` que vai percorrer essa `tab_2` `(SELECT ID FROM tb_2 WHERE NOME = 'AAA')`, nesse seu exemplo terão três registros, então é só ir inserindo cada um com seu novo `id` da `tb_2` e o mesmo `id` da `tb_1`.

### EX:

```
FOR _table2 in (SELECT ID FROM tb_2 WHERE NOME = 'AAA')

LOOP

   INSERT INTO tb_3 (tb_1_id,tb_2_id) VALUES(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tb_1,_table2.id)

END LOOP;
```

Comment: Isso, seria bem um loop mesmo, mas abriu uma luz aqui e percebi que daria pra resolver de um jeito muito simples, hehe. Desde já muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Achei a solução do jeito mais simples e que já fiz várias vezes. (até agora não caiu a ficha de que entrei nesse mundo de loop só pra isso).

```
INSERT INTO tb_3 (tb_1_id, tb_2_id) (
     SELECT (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tb_1) AS tb_1_id, ID AS tb_2_id 
       FROM tb_2 WHERE NOME = 'AAA')
```